# How to get select results using zeoslib

Tags: mysql, delphi

I am working on a project with mysql, and for this I am doing a class using zeoslib, I can make the connection, I can execute querys like insert, update, etc. But my problem is with select, I run it quietly, but how would I do to get the return? I would like something like PHP in that I inform the column name and it returns me the value of the row that is in that column.

Comment: Have you even worked with TDataSet descendants, like TTable, or the ADO components? I never used Zeos, but if TZQuery doesn't descend from TDataSet, there probably is another TZ component that does. After that ist's all standard, and you can probably look for tuts on how to link up *data aware controls* to a dataset. See for example: [Associating a Data Control with a Dataset](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/12ctrlsassociatingadatacontrolwithadataset_xml.html) in the Delphi documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important what you want to select, here is an example that uses TZQuery to get an integer value;

```
function TAccess.getProgramNo(aProgramName:WideString):Integer;
 var
  q:TZQuery;
begin
  Result := -1;
  q := TZQuery.Create(Self);
  try
      q.Connection := conn;
      q.SQL.Text := ' SELECT progno FROM programs WHERE name = :name ORDER BY progno ASC ';
      q.ParamByName('name').Value := aProgramName;
      q.Open;
      if q.RecordCount > 0 then
        Result := q.FieldByName('progno').AsInteger;
  finally
    q.Free();
  end;
end;
```

If you want to return a list of objects (i did not compile this);

```
function TAccess.getPrograms(aProgramName:WideString):TList;
 var
  q:TZQuery;
begin
  Result := TList.Create;
  q := TZQuery.Create(Self);
  try
      q.Connection := conn;
      q.SQL.Text := ' SELECT progno FROM programs WHERE name = :name ORDER BY progno ASC ';
      q.ParamByName('name').Value := aProgramName;
      q.Open;
      While not q.EOF do
        begin
          result.Add(TZoo.Create(....));
          q.Next;
        end;
  finally
    q.Free();
  end;
end;
```

Comment: you should use q.Free rather than q.Destroy().